# PHP class instance to JSON

Tags: php, json, object, encode

I'm trying echo the contents of an object in a JSON format. I'm quite unexperienced with PHP and I was wondering if there is a predefined function to do this (like json_encode()) or do you have to build the string yourself?
When Googling "PHP object to JSON", I'm just finding garbage.

```
class Error {
    private $name;
    private $code;
    private $msg;
    public function __construct($ErrorName, $ErrorCode, $ErrorMSG){
        $this->name = $ErrorName;
        $this->code = $ErrorCode;
        $this->msg = $ErrorMSG;
    }
    public function getCode(){
        return $this->code;
    }
    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function getMsg(){
        return $this->msg;
    }
    public function toJSON(){
        $json = "";

        return json_encode($json);
    }
}
```

What I want toJSON to return:

> { name: "the content of $name var", code : 1001, msg : error while
>   doing request}

Comment: prob wasn't around at the time of writing this, but if you are now using >5.4 you can have your class implement [JsonSerializable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You're just about there. Take a look at [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) in combination with json_encode and you'll have everything you need. Doing:

```
json_encode(get_object_vars($error));
```

should return exactly what you're looking for.

The comments brought up get_object_vars respect for visibility, so consider doing something like the following in your class:

```
public function expose() {
    return get_object_vars($this);
}
```

And then changing the previous suggestion to:

```
json_encode($error->expose());
```

That should take care of visibility issues.

Comment: I tried this before but it returned {}.
Guess I did something wrong before, thanks man!

Comment: AFAIK get_object_vars also takes into consideration the scope where it's called, so if you call it from a method inside the object, you will also have access to the private vars

Comment: `json_encode(get_object_vars($error));`will display public members, no privates.

Comment: Yeah, get_object_vars respects visibility, so you'll likely need to add a "expose" method or something similar to handle that. I'll add this suggestion to the answer.

Answer (score 46):

An alternative solution in **PHP 5.4+** is using the **JsonSerializable** interface.

```
class Error implements \JsonSerializable
{
    private $name;
    private $code;
    private $msg;

    public function __construct($errorName, $errorCode, $errorMSG)
    {
        $this->name = $errorName;
        $this->code = $errorCode;
        $this->msg = $errorMSG;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

Then, you can convert your error object to **JSON** with **json_encode**

```
$error = new MyError("Page not found", 404, "Unfortunately, the page does not exist");
echo json_encode($error);
```

Check out the example [here](https://3v4l.org/b9g9h)

[More information about \JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php)

Comment: Notice that the name of the class should've been MyError as the second code-snippet creates a new instance of MyError and not Error

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to make your variable public, in order for them to appear on `json_encode()`.

Also, the code you're looking for is

```
public function toJSON(){
    return json_encode($this);
}
```

Comment: I like this as I don't know of a way for get_object_vars to exclude properties you don't want to serialize.

Answer (score 6):

```
public function toJSON(){
    $json = array(
        'name' => $this->getName(),
        'code' => $this->getCode(),
        'msg' => $this->getMsg(),
    );

    return json_encode($json);
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/mPNGD6Gv

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, the following will write the value of a given class entry in a file `~/.config/scriptname/scriptname.conf`, create the file if it doesn't exist, and otherwise read and set back the class value at loading:

```
/* Example class */
class flag {
  static $COLORSET = ["\033[34;1m","\033[31;1m"];
}
/* Retrieve and set back values, otherwise create config file with the defined value --------------------------------------------------*/
if (!is_file($_SERVER["HOME"]."/.config/".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]."/".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"].".conf")){
    @mkdir($_SERVER["HOME"]."/.config/".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);
    @file_put_contents($_SERVER["HOME"]."/.config/".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]."/".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"].".conf",json_encode(["COLORSET"=>flag::$COLORSET]));
} else {
    flag::$COLORSET = json_decode(file_get_contents($_SERVER["HOME"]."/.config/".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]."/".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"].".conf"), true)["COLORSET"];       
}
```