# Converting or place a PHP array to class variables

Tags: php, arrays, class

How do I convert from my PHP array (mysql_fetch_array) to a declared PHP Class then encode that to json format string. My array:

```
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $patient[] = array( 'id' => $rows['id'],
                        'name' => $rows['name'], 
                        'sex' => $rows['sex'], 
                        'civil_status' => $rows['civil_status'],
                        'age' => $rows['age'], 
                        'type_of_admission' => $rows['type_of_admission'],
                        'admission_diagnosis' => $rows['admission_diagnosis'],
                        'date_admitted' => $rows['date_admitted']);
          }
```

My declare PHP Class

```
  class Person
    {
     public $id;
     public $name;
     public $sex;
     public $civil_status;
     public $age;
     public $type_of_admission;
     public $admission_diagnosis;
     public $date_admitted;
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Array to Object PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/convert-array-to-object-php)

Comment: Why do you need to populate a class before calling `json_encode()`? Just `json_encode` the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`mysql_fetch_object`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result, 'Person')){

    $json_rows[] = json_encode($row);

}
```

Also, you should be using [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), which has the [same basic concept](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php).

Comment: I believe this will probably help either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896254/php-class-instance-to-json

Comment: @AlejandroIván tnx I look to it now

Answer (score 0):

just retype to `(object)`

```
$object = (object) $array_name;
```

for [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: i want to place that $patient array to Person class then json_encode, how do i do it?