# json_encode empty with no error

Tags: php, json

I got an object. I need to turn into JSON for storage but when I try to encode it into JSON it returns an empty JSON object. When I tried to use `json_last_error`.

**The code I used**

```
echo $payload["sub"];
echo json_encode($user);
echo json_last_error_msg();
```

**The result I get**

```
"102573480781696194937{}No error".
```

**The User class I'm trying to encode**

```
<?php
    /**
     * Created by PhpStorm.
     * User: Student
     * Date: 13-4-2018
     * Time: 10:40
     */

    namespace php;
    class User
    {
        private $isAdmin = false;
        private $registeredFood = array();
        private $googleID;
        private $name;
        private $notes = array();
        private $email;

        /**
         * User constructor.
         * @param $googleID
         */
        public function __construct($googleID)
        {
            $this->googleID = $googleID;

        }


        /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getGoogleID()
        {
            return $this->googleID;
        }

        /**
         * @return bool
         */
        public function isAdmin()
        {
            return $this->isAdmin;
        }

        /**
         * @param bool $isAdmin
         */
        public function setIsAdmin($isAdmin)
        {
            $this->isAdmin = $isAdmin;
        }

        /**
         * @return array
         */
        public function getRegisteredFood()
        {
            return $this->registeredFood;
        }

        /**
         * @param array $registeredFood
         */
        public function setRegisteredFood($registeredFood)
        {
            $this->registeredFood = $registeredFood;
        }

        /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getName()
        {
            return $this->name;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $name
         */
        public function setName($name)
        {
            $this->name = $name;
        }

        /**
         * @return array
         */
        public function getNotes()
        {
            return $this->notes;
        }

        /**
         * @param array $notes
         */
        public function setNotes($notes)
        {
            $this->notes = $notes;
        }

        /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getEmail()
        {
            return $this->email;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $email
         */
        public function setEmail($email)
        {
            $this->email = $email;
        }
    }
?>
```

I hope someone can help me

Comment: JSON is meant for encoding data and will not work on classes or bits of code. I am not sure what contents you have in variable `$user`.

Comment: What do you expect it to encode? All properties are private.

Comment: @cars10m I got a User object stored in there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896254/php-class-instance-to-json

Comment: I would recommend you to look at PHP's [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface if you want complete control over the encoded json object.

Comment: Agreed @NigelRen approving duplicate designation

Comment: _Side note:_ This is just my opinion, but using "private" is rarely needed. (Not saying that it _never_ has a usage.) Using "protected" is, more often than not, a better approach since you then can access properties and functions more freely if you extend the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because your class's properties are private.

An example class with only private properties ...

```
php > class Foo { private $bar = 42; }
php > $obj = new Foo();
```

do not expose values:

```
php > echo json_encode($obj);
{}
```

But an example class with public properties ...

```
php > class Bar { public $foo = 42; }
php > $objBar = new Bar();
```

do it!

```
php > echo json_encode($objBar);
{"foo":42}
```

### \JsonSerializable

PHP provide an'interafce \JsonSerializable that require a method `jsonSerialize`. This method is automatically called by json_encode().

```
class JsonClass implements JsonSerialize {
    private $bar;
    public function __construct($bar) {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }
    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return [
            'foo' => $this->bar,
        ];
    }
}
```

I prefer this solution because is not good to expose publicly properties

### serialization and unserialization ...

If you need to serialize and unserialize php object you can ...

```
php > class Classe { public $pub = "bar"; }
php > $obj = new Classe();
php > $serialized = serialize($obj);
php > $original = unserialize($serialized);
php > var_dump($original);
php shell code:1:
class Classe#2 (1) {
  public $pub =>
  string(3) "bar"
}
```

$serialized variable contains `O:6:"Classe":1:{s:3:"pub";s:3:"bar";}`. As you can see is not a json, but is a format that allow you to recreate original object using unserialize function.

Comment: Gah! I was just about to post an answer using the JsonSerializable interface. You beat me to the punch :-p I totally agree though. JsonSerializable is the cleanest approach.

Comment: Is there a JsonDeserializable interface to revert the encoding back to object?

Comment: @LarsDormans - No. When it's converted to JSON, it's simply a JSON object. JSON is a simple notation for presenting data, it doesn't have any concept of functions or similar. It's no longer your class.

Comment: No, but you can `$serialized = serialize($obj)` and unserialize with `$original = unserialize($serialized)`. An object serialized is quite different from json but it allow you to send objects via http requests ^_^

Comment: Just a heads up on `serialize()`. That creates a serialized version of your class, but it isn't a "general" notation. It's PHP-specific, so if you want to be able to use that data in some other language, you would need to create a parser for it yourself.

Comment: @LarsDormans I've edited the answer about serialization and unserialization of php objects.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here.

**Option 1: Make your class properties `public`**

Like what `sensorario` mentioned, change the visibility of your properties so that it is accessible from outside the class, which is where you are calling `json_encode`.

**Option 2: Introduce a method/function within the class to return the encoded JSON object**

Have a `toJson()` function inside your `User` class.

Of course, there are way more options - such as extending `User` so that `User` is not "contaminated", etc.

But yup, the general problem is your `private` properties.