# Is file_put_contents a reliable way to check value of some variables?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, file-put-contents

My website is built with wordpress+woocommerce.

For learning purpose, I am trying to check an order's detail once it is completed using `file_put_contents`. Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'change_role_on_first_purchase' );

function change_role_on_first_purchase( $order_id ) {
  $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
  // $user = new WP_user($order->user_id);
  file_put_contents('order.json',json_encode($order));
  file_put_contents('userid.json',json_encode($order->user_id));
  }
}
```

While the second `file_put_contents` does write the correct user ID into `userid.json`, `order.json`'s content is just `{}`. Obviously `$order` is not empty, then why `file_put_contents` is outputting an empty json object?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697656/using-json-encode-on-objects-in-php-regardless-of-scope is relevant... for title of question though i would use `file_get_contents` ... or use a database

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you would choose to use file_put_contents?

Comment: @HowardE I am aware WP has its own debug method if that is what you mean. But for now `file_put_contents` is easier for me.

Comment: @HowardE And I will be very glad to learn in what kind of cases file_put_contents is incompetent.

Comment: I never said it was incompetent. I just asked you why. Debugging. I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Before you can json_encode($order), you need to get the order's data as a plain unprotected array:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$order_data = $order->get_data(); // ADD THIS
file_put_contents('order.json',json_encode($order_data));
```

**Long Answer**
Read: [json_encode empty with no error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893614/json-encode-empty-with-no-error)
TLDR: Basically, json_encode works best when an object has public properties. WC_Order doesn't have any, so it results in an empty object and that's why they created the get_data() method (to expose the data as a plain "unprotected" associative array) (perfect food for json_encode).