# foreach is returning empty

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have a little doubt about a loop that I am doing, because it is returning empty values.

First, I am receiving my items like this:

```
$items = Session::get('items');
$deco = json_decode($items, true);
```

If I return `$deco` I get this:

```
{
 "items":[
      {
        "id":1,
        "inventoryID":1,
        "title":"Product 1",
        "quantity":1,
        "unit_price":20,
        "image":"img.png"
      },

      {
        "id":2,
        "inventoryID":1,
        "title":"Product2",
        "quantity":1,
        "unit_price":25,
        "image":"img.png"
       }
    ]
}
```

Now, in the loop (which I use to change the values of some keys for the integration of paypal) I have this:

```
$results = [];
    foreach($deco['items'] as $element) {

        $name=$element['title'];
        $quantity=$element['quantity'];
        $sku= $element['id'];
        $price=$element['unit_price'];


        $item = new Item();
        $item -> setName($name)
        ->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setQuantity($quantity)
        ->setSku($sku) 
        ->setPrice($price);

        $results[]=$item;
    }
```

If I return `return $item`(outside the loop) I get (as expected) only one value, and not all of the collection:

```
{
"name": "Product2",
"currency": "USD",
"quantity": 1,
"sku": 2,
"price": "25"
}
```

But if I return `return $results` the var that I need, it gives me this (it does the {} of the items as I need, but returns empty):

```
[
{},
{}
]
```

**Thw whole code looks like:**

```
public function test(){
    $items = Session::get('items');
    $deco = json_decode($items, true);
    $results = [];
    foreach($deco['items'] as $element) {

        $name=$element['title'];
        $quantity=$element['quantity'];
        $sku= $element['id'];
        $price=$element['unit_price'];


        $item = new Item();
        $item -> setName($name)
        ->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setQuantity($quantity)
        ->setSku($sku) 
        ->setPrice($price);

        $results[]=$item;
    }  
    return $results;
}
```

EDIT: The `Item.php` model at `\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Api` is the default PayPal's:

```
class Item extends PayPalModel
{
/**
 * Stock keeping unit corresponding (SKU) to item.
 *
 * @param string $sku
 * 
 * @return $this
 */
public function setSku($sku)
{
    $this->sku = $sku;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Stock keeping unit corresponding (SKU) to item.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSku()
{
    return $this->sku;
}

/**
 * Item name. 127 characters max.
 *
 * @param string $name
 * 
 * @return $this
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Item name. 127 characters max.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Description of the item. Only supported when the `payment_method` is set to `paypal`.
 *
 * @param string $description
 * 
 * @return $this
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Description of the item. Only supported when the `payment_method` is set to `paypal`.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Number of a particular item. 10 characters max.
 *
 * @param string $quantity
 * 
 * @return $this
 */
public function setQuantity($quantity)
{
    $this->quantity = $quantity;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Number of a particular item. 10 characters max.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getQuantity()
{
    return $this->quantity;
}

/**
 * Item cost. 10 characters max.
 *
 * @param string|double $price
 * 
 * @return $this
 */
public function setPrice($price)
{
    NumericValidator::validate($price, "Price");
    $price = FormatConverter::formatToPrice($price, $this->getCurrency());
    $this->price = $price;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Item cost. 10 characters max.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPrice()
{
    return $this->price;
}

/**
 * 3-letter [currency code](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/).
 *
 * @param string $currency
 * 
 * @return $this
 */
public function setCurrency($currency)
{
    $this->currency = $currency;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * 3-letter [currency code](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/).
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCurrency()
{
    return $this->currency;
}
//More similar stuff
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `If I return return $item(outside the loop)` <= It's undefined outside the loop, are you sure you can do that?

Comment: @CaddyDZ, makes me think there is some `{` `}` mismatch or something going on here...

Comment: I think that `Item` is a dirty model that is not being saved, try to run `dd($item)` before `$results[]=$item` to see if `$item` is not a an empty object

Comment: The code you have posted works fine. https://3v4l.org/csXiO

Comment: You re init $item in every loop, you only get the last item of the array if you return $item after the loop

Comment: How are you inspecting the return results? Looks to me like you're using json_encode or something. Consider using var_dump to inspect the return result.

Comment: @CaddyDZ I think so, I have done some loops like that and works fine, becouse how else could I??
Also, if I dd($item) It returns the first value fine, as suposed to do

Comment: @Nick, You rigth, so could be a PayPal Item issue??

Comment: @catcon So, how should I do to get the items? is'nt the creation in every loop to get the collection of items?

Comment: @S.Imp I am using postman to get the returns, and just trying to see the var contains with return

Comment: @CaddyDZ: PHP's variables have a single scope except with function, so if OP defines $item inside the loop, $item is not undefined after the loop.

Comment: Thanks @catcon, that's true, tho it doesn't seem like a good idea to me

Comment: @S.Imp is asking the right question... you say  _"if I return `return $results`"_ but that doesn't mean anything. You _return_ to what? What do you do with the returned value? Just returning something from a script doesn't add it to the HTTP response, typically you need to `echo` something for that to happen

Comment: Can you post as well the model class? Did you hide the fields with the $hidden property in the model?

Comment: I'm betting that PHP does not know how to serialise your `Item` class as JSON. See [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38442923/283366) for a solution

Comment: @Phil if he is using Laravel correctly and Item extends the base model class there should be no issues with returning the data like that. (The base class implements the JsonSerializable interface correctly)

Comment: @mdexp we won't know until OP answers your question above.

Comment: @mdexp I just edit the original question with the model Item of paypal

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of the JMS serialization only.
I guess in the controller level you might have to check is there any serialization groups has been applied or not.

Answer (score 0):

The answer (thanks to Ionica on discord's laravel community) is:

```
    $items = Session::get('items');
    $deco = json_decode($items,true);
    $itemList = new ItemList();

foreach($deco['items'] as $element) {

    $item = new Item();
    $item->setName($element['title'])
        ->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setQuantity($element['quantity'])
        ->setSku($element['id']) 
        ->setPrice($element['unit_price']);

    $itemList->addItem($item);
}

$arr = $itemList->toArray();
return $arr;
```